# Ansible regrex insert or matching question

Tags: regex, replace, ansible

I have a question on the best way to go about matching strings on a per line basis. I have a file that has the following lines.

```
set interfaces vlan unit 1040 description line-v0 1040 1077 1413 2239 2412 2413 2414 413 743-1g28
set interfaces vlan unit 1077 description line-v0 1040 1077 1413 2239 2412 2413 2414 413 743-1g28
```

I am trying to use the Ansible replace module to do the following:

```
set interfaces vlan unit 1040 description line-v1040-1g28
set interfaces vlan unit 1077 description line-v1077-1g28
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to match this pattern and remove the extra text. Any help would be great!

Comment: Hi Matt, welcome to SO. I can't tell if the bold numbers are because you bolded them or if those are asterisks that appear in your text. Can you please format your question reasonably. There is quite a bit of [helpful documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting I will have to test your solution. I managed to find my answer on another forum using capture groups and referencing it again after it matches/replaces.  \g< string >  is how you call a capture group in Ansible which i didn't know about.

```
- name: Find and replace 3000
  replace:
    path: "~/ansible-depo/config/{{ ansible_host }}_set_vlan_desc.set"
    regexp: '(?<=(?P<vlanid_match>(\s[3][0-9][0-9][0-9])))\s?'
    replace: ' description "uplink-v\g<vlanid_match>-{{ ansible_host }}"'
  ignore_errors: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the lines are stored in replace-01.txt. Is this the code that you're looking for?

```
- replace:
    path: replace-01.txt
    regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
    replace: "{{ item.replace }}"
  with_items:
    - { regexp: "unit 1040.*$", replace: "unit 1040 description line-v1040-1g28" }
    - { regexp: "unit 1077.*$", replace: "unit 1077 description line-v1077-1g28" }
- debug: msg="{{ item }}"
  with_lines: "cat replace-01.txt"


> ansible-playbook replace-01.yml | grep msg
    "msg": "set interfaces vlan unit 1040 description line-v1040-1g28"
    "msg": "set interfaces vlan unit 1077 description line-v1077-1g28"
```